# What is cbc_param when we use pkcs11.C_EncryptInit

Tags: hsm, gemalto, softhsm

Moving from PTK to Luna and now in code, I need to pass `cbc_param`, before the inside object was the only mechanism.

Can somebody explain what is this about?
How PTK manage `cbc_param`?
What is the difference with and without `cbc_param`?

```
var cbc_param = pkcs11.C_GenerateRandom(new Buffer(16));

pkcs11.C_EncryptInit(
    session,
    {
        mechanism: pkcs11js.CKM_AES_CBC,
        parameter: cbc_param
    },
    secretKey
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PKCS11](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v2.40/os/pkcs11-curr-v2.40-os.pdf) documentation CBC mode has a 16-byte initialization vector (IV) parameter. This parameter is mandatory, basically it is 16 random bytes that you need use to encrypt/decrypt in CBC mode. It's ok to save it with cipher text, IV don't have to be a secret, but it must be random.